# Is there a way to create a shared document library between team sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, team-sites, modern

We have team sites for each department, one particular department requires shared resources for a particular document library.

e.g. Site A, B and C each have Library 1, but they see the same things inside.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

EDIT: Ideally, this would not require the user to navigate off their own site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new site, library share that with the Team A, B and C and add that library link to menu on each site. Alternatively you can have that library on Team A site and share that with the Team B and C and add link on the menu.

Comment: Was afraid this would be the case. Seems rather unintuitive to have to create another site but this seems to be the cleanest option right now (in the modern interface, at least). If I don't discover a better alternative, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: So this is what I put in place but the downside is that from the Team Site, the modern search doesn't include the new library site. Don't want to spend too much time on this so I suppose we'll just have to accept it and lump it in with training/governance.

Comment: You would have to play with Result Sources (old scopes) a bit to resolve that. You can easily create a new scope that will include Site A Plus the Shared Site and use that scope as default on site A then do the same for the other sites (setting scope respectively to them and shared library so in essence you will need 3 custom scopes).

Comment: That is really good actually - also just came across: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search
Which explains what changes impact both modern and classic - lot of trial & error and digging to find out some things about SharePoint I've found!